Entity LAZY loading cache in spring boot
I have an entity:
public class UserClassRegistration{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "email", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    User user;


    @JoinColumn(name = "class_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "semester", referencedColumnName = "semester", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Class aClass;

}

My entity Class need a lot of read, but a little write, so I want to cache it, by anyway (When call by LAZY call in this entity, or by another service)
It has composite Primary Key:
public class Class {
    @EmbeddedId
    @Expose
    ClassPK classPK;

    String timetable;

    int maxStudent;
}

And its PrimaryKey:
public class ClassPK {
    @Column(name = "id")
    String id;

    @Column(name = "semester")
    String semester;
}

I know some ways, like adding @Cacheable to method:
@Cacheable(value = "classes")
Class findByClassPK(ClassPK classPk) 

In interface: ClassRepository extends JpaRepository<Class,ClassPK>
But seem no effect, because I added properties
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.cache=TRACE

And I call my API twice, It still queries 2 times.

If you are using JPA don't use Spring Cache to cache the entities. Leverage the 2nd level cache of Hibernate instead. This will save you a lot of headaches with cache invalidation etc. etc.

How can I use that, I am beginner to caching, please explain more.

My question is: caching that Object (or Entity) (or Query) by anyway because I know i have a lot of read.

Sure you can cache but use your JPA provider capabilities and don't use @Cacheable from Spring. As you will have to manage also the parts where they need to be evicted, reloaded etc. etc. This is already all build into Hibernate and used and tested by lots of others. So use that instead. How to configure it check the 2nd level caching guide of Hibernate.
